# Работа над списками в Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Допустим, есть список ds:

```
ds = [d0,d1,d2..d(n-1)]
```

Нужно создать новый список:

```
ds1 = [(0, d0, abs(d0)), (1, d1, abs(d1)),..,(n-1, d(n-1), abs(d(n-1))]
0,1,...- последовательный номер 
d0,d1,..- элементы списка ds
abs - функция
```

Как это лучше сделать в Haskell?

У меня получилось сделать с помощью WinGHCi, но как-то коряво:

```
> let ds = [2,8,6,5,4,5]
> zip [1..] ds
[(1,2),(2,8),(3,6),(4,5),(5,4),(6,5)]
> let sqrall x = map (^2) x
> sqrall ds
[4,64,36,25,16,25]
> zip (ds1) (sqrall ds)
[((1,2),4),((2,8),64),((3,6),36),((4,5),25),((5,4),16),((6,5),25)]
```

А когда пробую объединить по-другому, сразу три списка, - высвечивается ошибка. В идеале, мне бы, конечно, хотелось именно написать как код внутри программы, но не знаю, как к нему подступиться.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста вашу собственную попытку и что пошло с ней не так

Comment: у меня получилось объединить 2 списка let ds = [2,8,6,5,4,5]

Comment: И какая проблема встала на вашем пути? Опишите, что не работает, какие ошибки выдаёт компилятор, или в чём там ещё проблема?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `zip3` или `zipWith`. В качестве списка индексов можно взять `[0..]`

Comment: Я дополнила задание, а то мне в Коментарии не так удобно писать код)

Comment: @extrn `zip3 [1..] (ds) (sqrall ds)` Дал желаемый результат, спасибо))

Comment: @Анна только если верить заданию, вам не в квадрат нужно возводить, а получить модуль числа. Ну и индексы должны начинаться с нуля. В остальном все верно.

Comment: Для примера указала модуль, главное понять алгоритм:) Дааа, за индексы спасибо, что напомнили.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию `zipWith` для двух списков, так как в задаче третье значение кортежа это функция от второго, то есть третий список нам не нужен, как и промежуточная функция `sqrall`:

```
let ds = [2,8,6,5,4,5]
zipWith (\a b->(a, b, abs(b))) [0..] ds
```

Функция в Вашем примере делает не совсем то, что описано в задаче: она возвращает кортежы формы `((a,b),c)` вместо `(a,b,c)`